# Check if the first three columns of every row has a substring

Tags: r, substring, apply

I have a data set that is as below.

```
Proc1   Proc2   Proc3  Count
AAZ      BLA     C       5
D        AAZ     E       7
A        G       F       1
T        X       Y       10
```

I have another vector that is as below.

```
Procs <- c("A", "B")
```

I wish to filter the rows containing A and B in any of the first 3 columns. The output I want is as below.

```
Proc1   Proc2   Proc3   Count
AAZ     BLA       C       5
```

Please let me know if there is a good way to achieve this.
Tried using %like% in the apply function but unable to get the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method using `sapply` with `rowSums` and `grep`. Two separate calls to `grep` check for the existence of "A" and "B". `sapply` performs these checks over the entire data.frame and returns matrices. `rowSums` sum these logical matrices by row. The results are multiplied so that if either "A" or "B" is missing from a row, a zero is returned. Finally a check is performed as to whether the retult is greater than 0.

```
keepers <- rowSums(sapply(df[1:3], function(x) grepl("A", x))) * 
           rowSums(sapply(df[1:3], function(x) grepl("B", x))) > 0

df[keepers,]
  Proc1 Proc2 Proc3 Count
1   AAZ   BLA     C     5
```

---

It is possible, though messy to make this more dynamic. You can wrap the `rowSums` function in an `sapply` and feed the `sapply` the vector of patterns. This will return a matrix of rowSums. You can then use `apply` to apply the `prod` function over each row and then check for positive instances.

```
keepers <- apply(sapply(c("A", "B"),
                        function(i) rowSums(sapply(df[1:3], function(x) grepl(i, x)))),
                 1, prod) > 0

keepers
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Moreover, inside grepl, I need to specify the vector not a specific pattern since the pattern will be given by the user. This would not work for such a scenario.

Answer (score 1):

We loop through the 'Proc' columns, check whether the elements contain both 'A' and 'B' to return a `list` of logical `vector`, `Reduce` it to a single `vector` by comparing the corresponding elements of `vector`s for any element in a row that match the criteria, and use that to subset the dataset rows.

```
pat <- paste(paste(Procs, collapse=".*"), paste(rev(Procs), collapse=".*"), sep="|")
df1[Reduce(`|`, lapply(df1[grep("Proc", names(df1))], grepl, pattern = pat)),]
#  Proc1 Proc2 Proc3 Count
#1   AAZ   BLA     C     5
```

---

Or another option is to `paste` the elements in rows together and do a single `grep`

```
pat <- paste(paste(Procs, collapse="[^,]*"), paste(rev(Procs), collapse="[^,]*"), sep="|")
df1[grep(pat, do.call(paste, c(df1[grep("Proc", names(df1))], sep=","))),]
#  Proc1 Proc2 Proc3 Count
#1   AAZ   BLA     C     5
```

#### Data

```
Procs <- c("A", "B")
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. But the pattern won't be fixed. They will be taken from the user in the form of a vector, eg: Procs

Comment: @Jishu Updated the post to make it more dynamic

Comment: @Jishu Infact, `lapply` is much faster and efficient compared to converting it on a logical matrix (as it will cost the memory)

Answer (score 1):

```
Procs <- c("A", "B")

# unite all the columns you are interested to search in. Thanks to @DavidArenburg for the improvements
xxx = do.call(paste0, df[1:3])
#> xxx
#[1] "AAZBLAC" "DAAZE"   "AGF"     "TXY"   

# now iterate through the above vector and apply grepl, if the totalSum matches the 
# length of Procs - it means all characters in the Procs were present in the value of xxx

ind <- which(rowSums(sapply(Procs, grepl, xxx, fixed = TRUE)) == length(Procs))
df[ind,]
#   Proc1 Proc2 Proc3 Count
#1:   AAZ   BLA     C     5
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg would this be a comparable approach?

Comment: Not sure why you ask me, but I think there is no need in `lapply/data.frame` combo, just use `sapply` instead. And you could add `fixed = TRUE` some performance inhacment. Something like `ind <-rowSums(sapply(Procs, grepl, xxx, fixed = TRUE)) == length(Procs)`. Also, `xxx` could be just `xxx <- do.call(paste0, df[1:3])` (without packages)

Comment: this is the reason why I asked you, you always have given efficient improvements to my answer. Thanks again